# Fatel error message when saving post/pages

Tags: error-message

Why do I sometimes receive the following message when I save a change made to a page:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributes() on a non-object
>   in
>   /nfs/c04/h06/mnt/181592/domains/imperfectinteriors.co.uk/craft/app/controllers/EntriesController.php
>   on line 444

Although it is an error message, the save is successful and the change is reflected in the site.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Patrick, that sounds like a bug. Can you please send us a ticket from your dashboard the next time you see it, along with an explanation of what you did? Make sure that the DB backup checkbox is checked when you send in the ticket.

Comment: Closing this as a bug. Patrick, feel free to reach out to Pixel & Tonic for support on this issue, they are incredibly friendly and happy to help! For more information, see ["How do I submit a bug/issue with Craft?"](http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29/how-do-i-submit-a-bug-issue-with-craft)

Comment: Thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction.